# Override Registration Controller with fosuser Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\RegistrationController"

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I am trying to override the FosUserBundle Registry Controller, but the following error appears:

`Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\RegistrationController": argument "$formFactory" of method 
"FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct()" 
references interface "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface" but no such service exists. 
You should maybe alias this interface to one of these existing services: "fos_user.profile.form.factory", "fos_user.registration.form.factory", "fos_user.change_password.form.factory",
"fos_user.resetting.form.factory". Did you create a class that implements this interface?`

I'm using Symfony4 and this is my `RegistrationController.php` code.
I've tried multiple ways, but I can't find a way to make it work.

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
        {

            public function registerAction(Request $request)
            {

                $form                = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
                $formHandler         = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
                $confirmationEnabled = $this->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

                die("Hello");

                $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
                if ($process) {
                    $user = $form->getData();

                    if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                        $this->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                        $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
                    } else {
                       // $this->authenticateUser($user);
                        $route = 'users_edit';
                    }

                    $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
                    $url = $this->get('router')->generate($route, array("id" => $user->id));

                    return new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                return $this->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()
                ));
            }


        }
    ?>
```

Comment: For other readers, SF4 has stopped support of child bundles, which is how the existing FOSUser docs suggest this. SF4 does let you directly override services/controllers, and this is the logical way to replicate the former behaviour. Whats mysterious is why the referenced Factory works for FosUser directly, but not in the overridden class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

work in symfony 4.2

services.yaml

```
App\Controller\RegistrationController:
    arguments:
        $formFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
```

and controller

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as Base;

class RegistrationController extends Base
{

    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        parent::__construct($eventDispatcher, $formFactory,$userManager, $tokenStorage);
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem , with SF4 and FOSUserBundle. After looking around for half a day I come with a solution. I use some material from @thibaut and adapt it to SF 4.2.

I inject the services needed by fos user registration controlleur and give FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface an alias

config/services.yaml

```
   app.controller.register:
    class: App\Controller\bundles\FOSUserBundle\RegistrationController
    arguments:
        $eventDispatcher: '@event_dispatcher'
        $formFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
        $userManager: '@fos_user.user_manager'
        $tokenStorage: 'security.token_storage'
    calls:
        - method: setContainer
          arguments:
              - '@service_container'
    public: true   

FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface:
    alias: 'fos_user.registration.form.factory' 
    public: true
```

Then in my registration controller, I redeclare a constructor and save formfactory to be use in the controller

App\Controller\bundles\FOSUserBundle

```
protected $formFactory;

public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, $serviceContainer=null)
{
    $this->setContainer($serviceContainer);
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;

    parent::__construct($eventDispatcher, $formFactory, $userManager, $tokenStorage);
}
```

use the declare $formfactory in my action

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="registration")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{


    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->formFactory;
    /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
```

Hope it also help you guys

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of `FOSUserBundle` are you using but there is no official support for `sf4` yet - see [release notes](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/releases). You can try `dev-master` version and follow [this issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2639) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hooks and avoid override controllers in FOSUserBundel v2.x
More information you can read on the page: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an alias for the FOS services that were refusing to autowire in my `config/services.yaml`

`FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FormFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'`

As seen in `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/registration.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think i have found a way to handle this problem:
 Define your service:

```
app.controller.register:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\RegisterController
    arguments: ['@service_container']  
    public: true
```

then your controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

/**
 * @Route(service="app.controller.register")
 */
class RegisterController extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct($serviceContainer=null)
    {
        $this->setContainer($serviceContainer);
        $eventDispatcher=$this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
        $formFactory=$this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        $userManager=$this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $tokenStorage=$this->container->get('security.token_storage');

        parent::__construct($eventDispatcher, $formFactory, $userManager, $tokenStorage);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="register")
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

hope this help (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in an override:

- Do a full override of the FOSUserBundle RegistrationController i.e. copy its entire contents to AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php
- Then replace the __construct function with the below:

  ```
  public function __construct() {
      $this->eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
      $this->formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
      $this->userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
      $this->tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage'); }
  ```

Voila! You are just calling these services in the constructor instead of passing them in as parameters in a registration controller service.

I did this now & it works for sf3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , with SF4, FOSUserBundle (behind SonataAdmin). 
I wanted listen an event : Registration confirmed, to send a message to the admininstrator.
my first try : override the FosUser controller. But the issues are many !
Thanks to @majne, I went to http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html, and, even I am not in 'master', that works, hooking the event, from FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents class.
I had some problems to cleary adapt the use statements...

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 4.2 the following should work.

Contrary to what is suggested in other answers, there was no need to extend the corresponding FOSUserBundle controller or modify the `__construct` method.

/config/services.yaml

```
FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
```

In my case I actually overrode both the `RegistrationController` and the `ResettingController` and in that case one needs to wire both forms - and also the `MailerInterface` - as so:

/config/services.yaml

```
FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface:   '@fos_user.resetting.form.factory' 

FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface: '@fos_user.mailer.default' 

App\Controller\RegistrationController:
    autowire: true
    arguments: 
        $formFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solve it by making "fos_user.resetting.form.factory" public

```
#fos_user.yaml 
services:
    new_service_name:
        alias: fos_user.registration.form.factory
        public: true
```

Then use the service with the new name

```
$form = $this->get('new_service_name');
```

Comment: You really think changing code under the vendor directory is a good idea?  Not that it would fix the error anyways.